# Wrap text around a table in a poster documentclass

Tags: tables, wrapfigure, a0poster

I have checked many questions in Stack Exchange for 'wrapping text around table', but they haven't solved my issue (most of them for article documentclass).

I'm making an A0 poster in Overleaf, and I want to put a table to the right side of some text; so just wrap the text around the table. I have tried wraptable, wrapfigure and minipage, but none have helped. The Overleaf source file with the latex code is given below; the generated PDF shows text encroaching the table, instead of wrapping around it. Please help me solve this.

Latex code:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Specify colors by their 'svgnames', for a full list of all colors available see here: http://www.latextemplates.com/svgnames-colors

\usepackage{times} % Use the times font
\graphicspath{{figures}} % Location of the graphics files
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for table
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows wrapping text around tables and figures
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% User defined packages
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[citebordercolor=white]{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{white}{
%------------------
%   POSTER HEADER 
%------------------

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.90\linewidth}
\centering
\color{NavyBlue} \Huge \textbf{title}
\color{Black}\\[0.8cm] 
\Large \textbf{
\authorName{Author}
}\\[0.2cm]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.10\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{}
\end{minipage}
}

%------------------
%   Results & Discussion
%------------------
\section*{Results and Discussion}

\noindent
Here I start explaining the table. I want this explanation to be wrapped around the table. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.

\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.25\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
 \hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$\gamma$} \\
 \hline
  & Quantity1 & Quantity2 & Quantity3 & Quantity4 \\
 \hline
  Quantity1 & 0.89 & 0.87 & - & 0.86 \\
  Quantity2 & 0.95 & 0.92 & - & - \\
  Quantity3 & - & 0.92 & - & - \\
  Quantity4 & - & - & 0.80 & - \\
 \hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$\beta$} \\
 \hline
  & Quantity1 & Quantity2 & Quantity3 & Quantity4 \\
 \hline
  Quantity1 & 0.89 & 0.87 & - & 0.86 \\
  Quantity2 & 0.95 & 0.92 & - & - \\
  Quantity3 & - & 0.92 & - & - \\
  Quantity4 & - & - & 0.80 & - \\
 \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption. \label{table:stats}}
\end{wraptable} 

{
\noindent
Whatever I put here comes to the left of the table, but it crosses over the table instead of wrapping back when it reaches the table. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't link to an external source as it might disappear. Provide the MWE code in your question.

Comment: Done. Thank you @PeterWilson

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable. Remove packages that are not necessary to compile your MWE, and instead put those packages and definitions which are needed. I get several errors upon compilation which might or might not be related to your problem.

Comment: I think that the problem is rooted in the fact that you enclose the last paragraph (the one that you want to wrap around the tabular) in curly braces (`{}`). If you remove the curly braces, it should work.